# Person Account issues - Your account record type is missing, a duplicate, or invalid. Ask your admin to check the individual record type

Tags: person-accounts, health-cloud

Having this issue on a dev org. Mappers, record types etc. seems to be in place. Trying to use the default Person Account. Checked all documentations and all the crap out there but no luck so far.

Anyone had this issue and how did you get to fix it ?

```
HealthCloudGA.AccountTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: HealthCloudGA.MoiExceptionWrapper.ValidationException: Your account record type is missing, a duplicate, or invalid. Ask your admin to check the individual record type configurations in Setup.
```

Comment: have you looked at the following [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318117&type=1) for this error?

Comment: Yeah, that any many others but anything i do seems to have no effect at all.